# Unusual Behaviour of printf statement inside loop

Tags: c, for-loop, primes, divide-by-zero

I am new to programming world, I made a program to check if the given number is prime or not, but it is showing unusual behaviour.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            printf("n is not a prime number!");
            break;
        }
        if (i == n - 1)
        {
            printf("n is prime!");
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Enter n:5
n is prime!
```

Actual Output:

```
Enter n:5
```

Reference [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwciI.png) 
Using VS Code and MinGW.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Consider what your loop body does in the first loop iteration when `i` is `0` and also the second loop iteration when `i` is `1`.

Comment: Doing modulus using zero as a divisor causes your program to crash.  Checking whether a number is divisible by one is not informative either; your code will report that every number is not prime.

Comment: But As I know taking modulus with zero will give zero, then loop should keep running?

Comment: You know wrong.  Modulus with zero will not yield zero on most systems.  It will yield a “floating point exception” (a historic misnomer) on most machines.  It is definitely undefined behaviour   and hence any result is possible and acceptable.

Comment: One more thing you should consider is just limit the `for` loop to `sqrt(n)`, because if `n=a*a` then we have `n=b*c` with  `b<a` and `c>a`. It will improve the performance.

Comment: @Becker I am not able to understand, will you please show me an illustration?

Comment: @FamilyAccount, aside: rather than `i <= n - 1`, use `i < n`.  It is easier to code, understand and is well defined for all `int`, even `n == INT_MIN`.

Comment: Thanks @chux-ReinstateMonica, I am new to programming that's why I am doing silly mistakes in optimization of the code.

Comment: @FamilyAccount suppose you have `n=91` then `(int)sqrt(n)=9`, if `n%i!=0` with all `i` from `2` to `9` then can not exist a number in range `(9, 91)`  can be divided by `91`. Or for instance, you have `n=64=8*8=2*32` you can see `2<8` and `32>8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

In this for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
{
    if (n % i == 0)
    //..
```

there is division by zero when `i` is equal to 0.

Apart from this any number prime or not prime is divisible by 1. So in any case the approach with this for loop is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @VladfromMoscow for the solution and suggestions. It means taking mod with zero will not be valid, but why didn't compiler showed any error, at compilation.

Comment: @FamilyAccount Syntactically the code is valid.

Comment: It means compiler doesn't checks for operations taking place in the program, instead checks for syntax. Right?

Comment: @FamilyAccount Yes you are right.